# Highcharts plotted date is incorrect

Tags: parsing, datetime, highcharts

I am plotting time data, and passing it in UTC format, but for some reason the plot is showing the date as starting from "1 - jan - 0001"

I convert the epoch to date with the following code, and it is working correctly.

```
for(var i=0;i<timeData.length;i++){
    timeData1[i] = new Date(timeData[i]*1000);    
}
```

I then pass it into the chart as follows:

```
 xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     title:{ text:'Time'},
     series:[{
         name:'Time',
         data:timeData
     }]
 },
```

Comment: Could you show us what `timeData` looks like before and after? Also, is there a reason you use `timeData` in your `xAxis` instead of `timeData1`?

Comment: Your timestamps are correct ?

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts you can set series for chart, not for xAxis (at least not that way), so change from:

```
xAxis: {
   type: 'datetime',
   title:{ text:'Time'},
   series:[{
     name:'Time',
     data:timeData
   }]
},
```

to:

```
xAxis: {
   type: 'datetime',
   title:{ text:'Time'}
},
series:[{
   name:'Time',
   data:timeData
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem. My x-axis was hourly. But the first tick, for midnight, was labeled "1. Jan". The other labels were correct, 10:00 for 10 a.m. etc.

Fortunately Highcharts has a fix for that bug: just leave off the first label entirely.

showFirstLabel: false